# compare two lost and filter equals in ramda

Tags: javascript, regex, ramda.js

I have an array named `navLinks` which has a property named `requiredPermissions`; also and an array of permission's which named `userPermisssion`.
Now I want to  `filter` all `navLink` item based on that are them `requiredPermission` prop equal to `requiredPermission`.
My approach was simple, but I confused when it's come to list.

```
R.filter(R.equal(R.prop('requiredPermossions',x), ??? ))
```

EDIT:
for example, assume we have an array of objects named is `NavLinks` which has a property `userPermisssion =['FIN']` and have a list  `requiredPermission=['FIN','ADMIN']`. now we can say this user has permission for matching permissions navlinks. both variables are the list of string which indicates role and permissions.

Comment: Can you show us a small set of data, and what the expected output is?

Comment: @ScottSauyet  thank you for comment. question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got what you need. It is cleaner to pipe the commands. Here goes an example that does what you want:

```
const navLinks = [ 
    { requiredPermissions: ['FIN'] },  
    { requiredPermissions: ['FIN', 'ADMIN'] },
];

const userPermissions = ['FIN'];

const result = R.filter(
    R.pipe(
        R.prop('requiredPermissions'),
        R.all(R.flip(R.contains)(userPermissions)),
    ), navLinks);
```

The explanation goes like this:

1. The function used in filter is called with each object in navLinks
2. Inside the pipe we keep only the requiredPermissions list
3. For each item in the list we check if it is included in the userPermissions list. Only if all the permissions are included in userPermissions do we return true.